# All commands need administrative privileges

Tags: command-line, permissions, environment-variables

I've installed Hping3 on my Ubuntu 8.04, but after installation when I want to use Hping3 I got this error:

```
Command 'hping3' is available in '/usr/sbin/hping3'
The command could not be located because '/usr/sbin' is not included in 
the PATH environment variable. 
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges
associated with your user account.
```

also when I try to run `ifconfig` I get this:

```
Command 'ifconfig' is available in '/sbin/ifconfig'
The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in 
the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges
associated with your user account.
```

First I need to run `sudo su` and then run the command. Is this normal? Or am I missing something?

when I run `echo $PATH` I get:

```
 /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/home/amirreza/simulator/ns-allinone-2.33/bin:/home/amirreza/simulator/ns-allinone-2.33/tcl8.4.18/unix:/home/amirreza/simulator/ns-allinone-2.33/tk8.4.18/unix:/home/amirreza/simulator/ns-allinone-2.33/ns-2.33/:/home/amirreza/simulator/ns-allinone-2.33/nam-1.14/
```

Comment: Come to think of it, is this on a fresh install? Can you think of any reason your $PATH might be messed up?

Comment: Try adding /sbin and /usr/sbin to your current $PATH, separated by colons just like the rest.

Answer (score 3):

hping usually needs to be run as root (just like many other network analysis tools).

That said, both `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` should be in your $PATH. Not being able to run ifconfig is definitely not normal and a major annoyance. Here's my $PATH for your reference:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

You can display it using `echo $PATH` and edit it using `export`, like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

PS. My root $PATH is

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

... just in case.