# ifconfig : Command 'ifconfig' is available in '/sbin/ifconfig'

Tags: command-line, paths, ifconfig

My question is related to another open [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27734/all-command-need-privilage). My  echo $PATH gives me an output which is like

```
/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sahil/.rvm/bin{}:/home/android-sdks/{}:/home/android-sdks/platform-tools/{}:/home/android-sdks/tools/{}:/home/sahil/android-sdks/tools{}:/home/sahil/android-sdks/tools:/home/sahil/android-sdks/platform-tools/
```

But running

```
ifconfig
```

gives me an output like

```
Command 'ifconfig' is available in '/sbin/ifconfig'
The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
ifconfig: command not found
```

after running command like given in other question

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

it runs **ifconfig** but blocks other commands of ruby rails or rvm.

Seeking help how to resolve this. Also why this happens?

Comment: plz add the output of following command to the question: cat /etc/environment

Comment: BTW what Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Why this happens, is because your export command is overwriting your existing path.  If you want to keep your existing path and append to it, you need a missing piece of magic: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"  compare that to what is in your question and you will see what's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Try the command below

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

OR (if you want to set all the paths)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: please read carefully again my question what i have written.

Comment: add this line to your ~/.bashrc:
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin`

Comment: @konard sorry, it is not working.

Comment: After editing your rc files, I usually type `source ~/.rcFileName` to reload the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your original `$PATH` (the line you posted is not very readible):

```
/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:
/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:
/home/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/bin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:
/home/sahil/.rvm/bin{}:
/home/android-sdks/{}:
/home/android-sdks/platform-tools/{}:
/home/android-sdks/tools/{}:
/home/sahil/android-sdks/tools{}:
/home/sahil/android-sdks/tools:
/home/sahil/android-sdks/platform-tools/
```

You have `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin` and `/bin`. As you already found out `ifconfig` is inside `/sbin`.

So where that path is set you also need to include `/sbin`.

See [rubygems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12#page52) docs on how to do this.

Comment: and how do i do that ??

Answer (score 1):

/sbin is normally part of path. Other distros like fedora dont have it in PATH for normal users but I think Ubuntu always does. I will suggest you check your /etc/environment file and see if it is valid and has /sbin added to path. When I run **cat /etc/environment**, I get following output:

```
adnan@adnan-laptop:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

As you can see **/sbin** is already part of PATH environment variable. If your file has the same contents then check its permissions otherwise add /sbin to PATH in this file. For me the permissions are:

```
adnan@adnan-laptop:~$ ls -l /etc/environment 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 79 2009-10-29 01:55 /etc/environment
```

Comment: its same over here all things

Comment: Like Sahil, `/etc/environment` exists, has the correct permissions, and has the correct `PATH` inside it - but for some reason, all of a sudden, `bash` no longer uses it after a reboot today.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily solve this by adding `/sbin` to `$PATH`.  The more important point is that, **you should not have `/sbin` in the path by default**.

See this page for a description of why:
[`/sbin` directory definition](http://www.linfo.org/sbin.html)

`/sbin` contains system utilities that should be run by root or using sudo authority.  So if you want to see your network configuration simply type:

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig
```

You will be prompted for your password and then `ifconfig` will run.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the `PATH`variable?**

`PATH` is a list of directory paths. When the user types a command without providing the full path, this list is checked to see whether it contains a path that leads to the command. The order of paths in this variable indicates the order in which the command will be searched, in case there is a program by the same name in multiple directories the one located in the folder closest to the beginning of the list (left side) will be executed.

The reason why you got other commands blocked (from ruby rails and rvm) is because you executed this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

resulting in a `PATH` that **does not contain** the folders of such programs, namely:

```
/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/bin
```

What you should do instead is add `/sbin` to you own `PATH`.

**How to add `/sbin` to `PATH`**

As the `PATH` is basically always in the environment you don't need to export it, you just need to add the `/sbin` directory to it. In order to do that you can execute in your bash

```
PATH="$PATH:/sbin"
```

your path now should look something like this:

```
/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/sahil/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sahil/.rvm/bin{}:/home/android-sdks/{}:/home/android-sdks/platform-tools/{}:/home/android-sdks/tools/{}:/home/sahil/android-sdks/tools{}:/home/sahil/android-sdks/tools:/home/sahil/android-sdks/platform-tools/:/sbin
```

This change will not be permanent though, once your close your current session `PATH` will be reloaded with the previous value. In order to make it permanent you should add this change to your `~/.profile` file. One way of doing it is the following:

```
echo 'PATH="$PATH:/sbin"' >> ~/.profile
```

Now you just need to execute the content of "~/.profile" in the current shell.

```
source ~/.profile
```

You are ready to go, not only your current shell but all your future sessions will have the `PATH` containing the directory.

**Why did i use ~/.profile instead of ~/.bashrc?**

This concept can be useful for you:

> - `~/.profile` is the place to put stuff that applies to your whole    session, such as programs that you want to start when you log in (but 
>     not graphical programs, they go into a different file), and
>     environment variable definitions.
> - `~/.bashrc` is the place to put stuff that applies only to bash itself,    such as alias and function definitions, shell options, and
>     prompt       settings. (You could also put key bindings there, but for
>     bash they      normally go into ~/.inputrc.)

[You cant get more information about this topic here.](https://superuser.com/a/183980)

**Should you have `/sbin` in your `PATH`?**

I'm not going to discuss here if `/sbin` should or should not be in `PATH` by default because that can turn out to be not a very productive discussion to be had here. I have it, you can have it if you want. Your call.